# Finding large files in the history of a git repository fails

Tags: git, git-log, git-rev-list, git-verify-pack

My repository is very big because of some large files in the history. For finding the large files and removing them, I am executing:

```
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-..e8a.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -3
```

and the result is something like:

```
12eb660ea206e1b7bd42cb8b525aabe9e86a5064 blob   56413247 15833578 5889838
89b377ace5639c0914bb49d28d0c8e97b0f19a16 blob   56414112 15833631 81736530
4ea83fb57b49f7afdbe99e4f043509d184338f5b blob   56426618 15837504 48628334
```

To find the path of the largest file, I run:

```
$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep 4ea83fb57b49f
```

and the result is:

```
4ea83fb57b49f7afdbe99e4f043509d184338f5b path/to/my/large_file
```

but, when I run `git log` on this file like:

```
$ git log --oneline --branches -- path/to/my/large_file
```

No log is shown. 
In addition, whenever I try to remove the binary file from history by:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter  \
'git rm --ignore-unmatch --cached path/to/my/large_file'
```

I receive:

```
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the path to large objects are located in different branches. Use `--all` in `filter-branch` command to remove large files from all the branches.

Comment: Thanks, long story for a simple answer. :) My mistake was not using --all at the end of 'git filter-branch'. Correct your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Actually the `filter-branch` command I posted already contains the --all parameter.